# How can i pause/play audio using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my audio in an `object` tag:

```
<object id="music" data="music.mp3">
    <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
</object>
```

I want to be able to pause/play the audio with a couple `a`tags:

```
<div id="music-on-off">Music: 
    <a href="#" id="music-on">On</a> | <a href="#" id="music-off">Off</a>
</div>
```

Can you tell me the jQuery to do this?

Comment: Why you insist to use `<a>` tag?

Comment: @Bla... Aesthetic reasons. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<audio>` element, `.play()`, `.pause()`

html

```
<audio src="music.mp3" autoplay loop></audio>
<div id="music-on-off">Music: 
    <a href="#" id="music-on">On</a> | <a href="#" id="music-off">Off</a>
</div>
```

javascript

```
 $(function() {
   var audio = $("audio")[0];
   var controls = {
     "music-on": "play",
     "music-off": "pause"
   };   
   function playPause(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     audio[controls[this.id]]()
   }
   $("#music-on, #music-off").click(playPause);
 });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j3eL1nL8/1/